# filling input using jquery an image

Tags: jquery, image, html, input, move

I'm a bit lost.
I really do not know if it is possible.
I have many image with number "1" ,"2", and so on...

The thing is that I would like to fill input by moving the image into the input.
Actually I need to write the number in the input, 
and I have many input so sometimes I can mislead.

By moving image I will know that a number is used if the image is not there.
So it should make disapear the image if the input has been fullfill with the image.

I really do not know if something like that is possible.
I've been looking for that for a long time, but I did not find anything.

Comment: if it's for a password code (which is the only functionality I can think of where you would need to do that) then you should not display the numbers in clear, otherwise you cannot have pictures in text input, you will need to write your own component I suppose.

Comment: Ok I understand. Thak you verry much for your precision.